# DevExpress XPO vs NHibernate vs Entity Framework: database upgrading issue

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, devexpress, upgrade, xpo

What is the best practice for upgrading the database using *ORM* ([DevExpress XPO](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/), [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) or [MS Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx))?

I'm starting a new project and have to pick an *ORM*. The development process requires of releasing intermediate test builds quite often and likely that each build will have changes in the database structure. Each new version has to upgrade the DB gently to keep current data.

For old solutions I would provide a set of SQL scripts for upgrading the database from *v1* to *v2*, from *v2* to *v3*, etc. and execute them sequentially.

But how is it going to work for *ORM*? Should I still write SQL scripts to upgrade the DB?

I understand that simple adding new fields wouldn't cause a problem (e.g. see [UpdateSchema() method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/DevExpressXpoSession_UpdateSchematopic) for XPO), but what if I have to split a table and reallocate current records into 2 new tables?

Comment: As this question is quite old, here is some refresh : [the database schema migration tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) of EF Core are very powerful and easy to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't comment on the other ORM's, but I have used DevExpress XPO for a corporate treasury application since 2007.  The schema changes a little with every release but there have also been some big schema changes over the years as well.  A somewhat extended version of the default XPO upgrade mechanism has comfortably catered for all the changes.

There is good basic information [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/CustomDocument2795) about upgrading XPO applications.

- DevExpress provide a DBUpdater tool to assist you with the task of upgrading production environments.  You can extend this tool to cater for additional requirements.  In my application, we have added some options for logging, preview with rollback, etc.
- Each module has virtual `UpdateDatabaseBeforeSchemaUpdate()` and `UpdateDatabaseAfterSchemaUpdate()` methods.  You can significantly control the upgrade process within these.

As you mention, some of the upgrade will be handled automatically by XPO (e.g., adding a new column), but some things need additional control such as initialising the new column with a default value for existing records.

For instance, let's say `MyNewField` has been added to the `MyEntity` XPO class in version 2.0 of your application. Let's say it should default to a value of 3 for existing records.  XPO will handle the creation of the new column but existing records will be NULL.  (If you specify a default value in the XPO class it would only pertain to new records).  In order to correct the value for existing records you would add something like the following to entity module's overridden `UpdateDatabaseAfterSchemaUpdate()`:

```
public override void UpdateDatabaseAfterUpdateSchema()
{
    base.UpdateDatabaseAfterUpdateSchema();
    if (CurrentDBVersion < new Version(2, 0, 0, 0))
        ObjectSpace.GetSession().ExecuteNonQuery(
            "UPDATE [MyEntity] SET [MyNewField] = 3 WHERE [MyNewField] IS NULL");
}
```

(You could also use `ObjectSpace.GetObjects<MyEntity>()` and a `foreach` if you prefer to avoid the direct SQL.)

In your more extreme example of splitting a table in two, you can use the same method, but you would override `UpdateDatabaseBeforeUpdateSchema()` instead, run the SQL to split the table, let XPO perform any other schema updates and, if necessary, populate any default values in the `UpdateDatabaseAfterUpdateSchema()`.

You will find that you bump into constraint problems e.g., foreign key violations so you might find you need to write some general routines such as `DropAllForeignKeyConstraints()` as part of the `UpdateDatabaseBeforeUpdateSchema()`.  Sometimes you find that XPO already provide something, sometimes not.  Missing constraints and indexes will get regenerated in the schema update.  (In my experience switching a master data table's primary key turned out to be the hardest update routine to get right.)

By default the calls all happen in an SQL transaction so if anything fails it should all roll back.

The developers need to be aware of when a change to the domain model is likely to cause a problem with the underlying schema.

For testing, we keep a few old customer databases and run a bunch of before-and-after tests as part of the build process to make sure that existing customers are able to upgrade properly whatever version they are upgrading from.  In production whenever we run into a problem upgrading, the problem data is added into this test library to prevent similar problems in the future.

We are dealing with major international companies and banks.  The customers are quite happy with the result.  In situations where a corporate's DBA needs to sign off on the changes, they don't seem to mind having a command line tool to do the upgrade rather than a script.

Comment: What you described relates to XAF, and not XPO specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Most migration solutions can handle easy tasks, like adding new column, relationship or removing one, but fail to work when you rename a column (is that an add? or a remove following an add which equals a rename? What should you do with the data in that case?)

All three solutions have basic migrations support, XPO even lets you run your own scripts as a part of the process (to insert static/test/contant data, etc.)

There's also the [MigratorDotNet](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) project that you can use and not to rely on any ORM specific feature regarding migrations.

Personally, I would use auto migration only in dev/test environment and would have full set of upgrade scripts when running on client specific database to say upgrade from v1 to v2.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I use [Apex SQL Tools](http://www.apexsql.com) to generate SQL script for upgrading. But my concern is that SQL scripts for upgrading kills the independence of ORM from database type.

Comment: But remembering the ORM is just there to address another problem, that is reading from / to the database. Upgrading the schema is just another problem that is best handled by another tool, being it Migrator.NET or external tools like Apex SQL Tools.

Answer (score 0):

> How is it going to work for ORM? Should I still write SQL scripts to
>   upgrade the DB?

Clear answer of this question should be on Programmer's stackexchange thread - [What are the criteria for evaluating an ORM for.NET?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9498/what-are-the-criteria-for-evaluating-an-orm-for-net), there i got simple answer for your question that you asked and matches with my experience with ORM while developing some project with Entity framework and Code smith ORM templates.

***How does the ORM manages changes in the data model?  what if I have to split a table and reallocate current records into 2 new tables?***

> Some can update the DB automatically within a certain measure, other
>   don't do anything and you'll have to do the dirty work yourself; other
>   provide a framework for handling change that lets you control database
>   updates. [That means every couple of days](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/41843/33403) someone needs to spend an hour updating the model to add a table or change datatypes that are changing

Ref:
  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6543/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-database-abstraction-by-orm
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41739/best-arguments-for-against-introducing-orm-technology-into-a-companies-dev-proce/41833#41833

Answer (score -1):

If you ask - what is the best practice for upgrading the db using ORM - my answer is: Don't use it if your application is more than a hobbyist app.

There are a lot of scenarios where many ORMs are unable to provide support to your specific database needs, e.g. in creating stored procedures, create indices and views or even indexed views/materialized tables without writing sql scripts. Problems like adding a new non-nullable column to an existing table are much harder to solve in ORM-Migration-Code than by writing SQL scripts.

Current Tools like Visual Studio Data Tools do handle these kind of problems way better.